# E-mail form sender name instead of e-mail ? (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, email, message

I've created a PHP email flooder and it works fine. However, while testing it, I'm only getting the sender e-mail address as the name. What I want is the name of the sender.

Below is the code.

Can someone help me please ? Thanks...

```
<?php     
$to  =  $_POST['to'];    
$from = $_POST['ot'];    
$subject = $_POST['tema'];     
$message = $_POST['message'];     

$headers .= "From: ".$from;     

if ($_POST['radio']==="plain")    
{    
$headers  = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";  
 $headers .= "From: ".$from;       
}    
elseif ($_POST['radio']==="html")   
{    
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";   
 $headers .= "From: ".$from;      
}    
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);     

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the html form too?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$headers .= "From: Name of the sender  <".$from.">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the form has a input field named "realname" y would write the following code:

```
<?php
$to  =  $_POST['to'];    
$from = $_POST['ot'];
$name = $_POST['realname'];
$subject = $_POST['tema'];     
$message = $_POST['message'];     

if ($_POST['radio']==="plain")    
{    
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";  
}
elseif ($_POST['radio']==="html")   
{    
    $headers  .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";   
}
$headers .= "From: $name <$from>";       

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```